# Code using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement throws exception when deployed in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to fetch all the groups to which the user belongs to and below is the code used to fetch all the groups of a user.

```
public void GetUserGroups(string userName)
{    
  UserPrincipal user = null;
  using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
  {
    // establish domain context
    PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    // find your user
    user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, userName);
  }
  // if found - grab its groups
  if (user != null)
  {
    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
  }
}
```

This works great in my development server, but when the code deployed in IIS, UAT server which is in DMZ, this code fails with the following stack trace:

```
Message:    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
   at LandingPage.GetUserGroups(String userName)
   at LandingPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

My problem is very similar to 
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement not working on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463466/system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-not-working-on-the-server) and used the same resolution but was of no help.

Please advise.

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())" makes it act as the identity of the application pool, the question is:  What is the identity on each of the application pools?  "NetworkService"?  "ApplicationPoolIdentity"?  A custom account?

To see that in IIS 7, first look at Basic Settings for the site, to see the name of its application pool.  Then click "Application Pools" in the left frame, and look at the Identity column for that application pool.

If the application pool for the site on the UAT server has a custom account, and it's a domain user, then start by setting up the development server's site, to use that same domain user as the identity for its application pool.

To change that in IIS 7, right-click the application pool, select "Advanced Settings", look for identity, click the "custom account" radio button, click "Set"...

(Side topic:  drawbacks to using "NetworkService" as the app pool identity, if your site uses SQL Server at all.  While what you are trying to do in windows, above, can be consistent -- setting up windows permissions for "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" -- the permissions for SQL Server would involve setup for at least 2 logons, since remote SQL Server access would be under user "DomainName\AspNetServer$".
For details, see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx
For example, for dev server "OURMIGHTYDEV", and UAT server "UATRULES", both in domain "DOMAINION" (you can tell I'm having fun making up these names;), could effectively have different identities, like login "DOMAINION\OURMIGHTDEV$", and login "DOMAINION\UATRULES$" -- and you'd have to setup matching permissions etc., for the 2 logins.)

Comment: Thank you very much Doug. The solution was bang on target.

Comment: You're welcome, Syed.  Based on your "bang on target", it sounds like your problem was permissions for the the application pool identity, on your development server.  If so, please confirm.  Did you simply choose to make the 2 servers/sites match?  And, if it's not revealing too much... did you go with a custom account / domain user, or "networkservice", or "applicationpoolidentity"?  (Remember StackOverflow is also for people who do an internet search on their problems, and who land on your question page, to find an answer... so whatever you think would give someone else an answer.) Thx.

Comment: Yes there was the problem with the permissions in the application pool identity. In the UAT server Application pool identity was set to custom account whereas in Dev server it was networkservice. First to test i made App pool identity to networkservice in UAT and it worked great for all Internal users but had problem fetching the group details for external users, so while creating the principal context object i am passing the domain and gave privileges to the custom account to fetch the group details.